# (Thread1:fatal error: index out of range error) showing this error in myCell.imageView?.image = myImages[indexPath.row]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    let myFruit: [[String]] = [["apple", "orange", "water mellon", "pineapple", "lemon", "Lime", "another fruit" ], ["green", "orange", "green/red", "yellow", "green"]]

    let myTitles: [String] = ["Fruits", "Color of Fruits"]

    let myImages: [UIImage] = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "dd"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "logo"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "nn"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "r"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "xx"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "zz")]

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return myFruit.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return myFruit[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return myTitles[section]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCoolCell", for: indexPath)
        myCell.textLabel?.text = myFruit[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        myCell.imageView?.image = myImages[indexPath.row]
        return myCell
    }
}
```

> (Thread1:fatal error: index out of range error) showing this error in  myCell.imageView?.image = myImages[indexPath.row]

Answer (score 1):

In `myFruit` array, there are 7 items inside the array at index 0. While the `myImages` has 6 items in it. You are returning `numberOfRowsInSection` as 7 (`myFruit[section].count`) so your app will crash when `indexPath.row = 6` because `myImages` array has items till `indexPath.row = 5`.

Either you should make sure your `myImages` array has always the same number of images as the `numberOfRowsInSection`.

OR

You can add a condition before accessing the image from `myImages` array as,

```
if indexPath.row < myImages.count {
    myCell.imageView?.image = myImages[indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: The problem is a lot worse than this. The code is getting the cell's text for multiple rows in multiple sections but there image is based on the row regardless of the section. That makes no sense at all. There needs to be a 1-to-1 match between the text and the image. There should only be one array of data, not two separate arrays of data.